# UK visa validity for Indian in Berlin, Germany

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, germany

I am Indian working in Berlin. My visa is valid until November 10th, 2018.

I'm planning to visit London. If I apply for a 6-month UK visa requesting a date from end of September. Can I leave Berlin the first week of November and stay in London for a while (~2 months, until New Year) and return to India from there directly?

My concern: since my German visa expires on November 10, will it influence the UK visa dates? Will the UK embassy set the end date of the UK visa to November 10 too?

Answer (score 4):

The edit makes this a different question - to me at least, and judging from the comment there's at least some agreement that my original answer (which had attracted one upvote, so it can't have been terribly far off) doesn't answer the edited question. My original answer is still present below.

When deciding whether they want to give you a visa the UK authorities looks at you and your circumstances. As they include the likelihood you'll leave the UK, where you can go might actually influence it. There are a lot more factors involved, so we can't guess what the UK authorities will do.

---

Original answer (to the unedited question):

Your plan involves leaving Schengen (Germany) before your Schengen visa expires, and being in the UK for a period where you'll have a visa for being there, so yes, you can do that (if you get that UK visa of course).

Comment: I read this question mostly as 'will I get a visa if I apply under these circumstances' which is completely not answered in this answer.

Comment: I agree, but this answer was written 2-3 minutes before an edit, that IMHO changed the question.

Comment: What ties to India can you demonstrate in order to convince UKVI that you have a compelling reason to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit? Conversely, do you have links in the UK (eg family) that might indicate a risk you wouldn't leave? Even if you get the visa, indicating a proposed travel date in September (with a valid Schengen return) but trying to enter U.K. in November may lead to a refusal at immigration.

Comment: @traveller i have my family living in UK and also in India. Now, i am more worried